# Defining array as class variable with user input for dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I wish to declare an array as a class variable but with dimensions input from the user.

```
class whatever
{
   int array[][]=new int [n][n]; //this is a wrong definition

   public void method()
   {
       //method content
   }
}
```

Here n is the required input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `n` as an argument to the constructor of your *`class`*<sup>**1**</sup>. Something like

```
class Whatever {
   int[][] array;
   public Whatever(int n) {
       this.array = new int[n][n];
   }

   public void method()
   {
       //method content
   }
}
```

<sup>**1** <sub>And, by convention, Java class names should start with a capital letter.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can pass array `size` trough constructor as a parameter and do like this.

```
class YourClass {

int[][] array;

public YourClass(int size){

       array=new int[size][size];

  }

public YourClass(int coloumnSize,int rowSize){

       array=new int[rowSize][coloumnSize];

  }

}
```

Hope it will help you.